# How to upload custom S3 metadata with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, fog

I want to add `Content-Disposition` header to a file I'm uploading with carrierwave (it's not an option to do it afterwards via query param in the URL).

Is there something I can add to the `AttachmentUploader` model that would help me accomplish this, before the file is uploaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set attributes either globally in your Carrierwave config -

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_attributes = {'Content-Disposition' => ...}
end
```

or you can define it on the uploader class itself

```
def fog_attributes
  {'Content-Disposition' => ...}
end
```

and the method on the uploader can use data accessible to the uploader to determine the appropriate return value for fog_attributes

Comment: Thanks! That's really great. Will it call fog_attributes automatically or do I need to call that from somewhere?

Comment: Carrierwave should handle calling the method if you've defined it on the uploader.

Comment: You are awesome -- Thanks so much. And I realize this is kind of un-kosher for Stack Overflow to ask like this, but trying to get help for AWS+Fog+Carrierwave is so sparse that I will try what I can... do you by chance have any insight to the following? https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1262

Comment: So I don't know the exact issue, but I do know that the fog_directory behaves differently if the format is a valid subdomain vs. a simple bucket name.  There appears to be some relevant info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270007/getting-exconerrorssocketerror-while-reading-images-from-one-s3-and-to-write .

Comment: Check out the public_url method here - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb .  I think you may be able to get around this by explicitly setting :endpoint in your fog configuration.  Set the endpoint to https://s3.amazonaws.com and that should force use of the directory style access

Comment: Excellent thanks man so much. And I have one final quick question (I promise :) ... considering that S3 tries to assign weird content types to some files, how might I leverage the MimeTypes gem in the fog_attributes method to set a content type? Right now I'm using ` MIME::Types.type_for(filename).first.content_type`

Comment: And that's great I'll checkout the second link you put. I swear this is great to get to get some help without hours of reading. This specific topic seems to have no real documentation, and all the questions are years old. progress is so slow, so thanks again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40786/discussion-between-peter-goldstein-and-tallboy)

Comment: I think fog ought to already do the MIME type stuff you mention there in most cases, but I could be wrong. Also, I commented on your carrierwave issue there. You can use `:path_style => true` in the credentials to force non-subdomain reference, which should match the cert. Hope that gets you what you need.