# How to set custom metadata when uploading image to s3 using carrierwave / carrierwave-aws?

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave with the carrierwave-aws gem to upload images to s3 from my rails app. 
The images upload fine, but I need to set custom metadata on the S3 objects as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

I don't see anything online about this. This SO post: [How to upload custom S3 metadata with Carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850241/how-to-upload-custom-s3-metadata-with-carrierwave) shows how to do it using the fog gem, i.e.:

`config.fog_attributes = {
      "x-amz-meta-test": "x-amz-meta-test"
    }`

but I am not using fog. Is there a way to do this using carrierwave-aws instead?

I tried

```rb
config.aws_attributes = {
      "x-amz-meta-test": "x-amz-meta-test"
    }
```

but it did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
  def aws_attributes     
    { metadata: { 'x-amz-meta-testing': 'test' }}
  end
```